# Filtering records when a particular event occurs

Tags: sql

I have the following dataset that lists payments made onto an account, the type of payment (either a regular payment, interest payment or additional payment) and the date of the payments.

```
ID  |  PAYMT_TYPE  |          AMT |  DTE 
123         REG                 100     JUN
123         REG                 100     MAY
123         REG                 100     APR
123         REG                 100     MAR
456         REG                 200     JUN
456         ADD                 100     JUN
456         REG                 200     MAY
456         ADD                 100     MAY
789         REG                 400     JUN
789         REG                 400     MAY
789         REG                 400     APR
789         REG                 400     MAR
```

Most accounts will simply have a REG payment made each month, however I want to pull out the ones that made both a REG and an ADD on the same date.

The query I have, below, will give me all the REG's and ADDs but will not group these by the ID. So I end up with a bunch of REG only accounts.

```
SELECT *
FROM PAYMENT_TABLE
WHERE  PAYMT_TYPE IN ('REG', 'ADD')
AND DTE BETWEEN '01-JUN-20' AND '01-JUN-21'
```

My ideal output would look like this :

```
ID  |  PAYMT_TYPE  |           AMT |  DTE 
123         REG                 100     JUN
123         ADD                 50       JUN
123         REG                 100      MAY
123         ADD                 50       MAY
456         REG               200     JUN
456        ADD                100     JUN
456         REG               200     MAY
456        ADD                100     MAY
789        REG                400     JUN
789        ADD                100     JUN
789        REG                400     MAY
789        ADD                100     MAY
```

Can anyone help? I feel like I am missing something obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
SELECT pt.*
FROM PAYMENT_TABLE pt
WHERE PAYMT_TYPE IN ('REG', 'ADD') AND
      DTE BETWEEN '01-JUN-20' AND '01-JUN-21' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM PAYMENT_TABLE pt2
              WHERE pt2.ID = pt.ID AND
                    pt2.PAYMT_TYPE IN ('REG', 'ADD') AND
                    pt2.PAYMT_TYPE <> pt.PAYMT_TYPE
             );
```

Or, if you only want the id/date combinations:

```
select id, dte
from payment_table
where paymt_type in ('REG', 'ADD')
group by id, dte
having count(distinct paymt_type) = 2;
```